# A formula for importing specific data into another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I need a function for column **K** of `Sheet1`, that says:

"If the row of Sheet2 contains the same RID number as a row in Sheet1, then fill Sheet1 with the email address located in column K of Sheet2"

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you still seeking an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have two Sheets, does this mean you have to separate Google Spreadsheets or you have two Sheets in one Google Spreadsheet? Both would require two sheets (tabs at the bottom) if you are pulling from an entire different sheet, use the =ImportRange("SHEET ID", "Range") function in the second tab to get the data.

As for the specifics of the question.

This is formula that you will use in column K in Sheet1

```
=IF(Sheet2!A1 = A1, Sheet2!K1, "")
```

This is assuming if course that your RID is located in the A column of the second sheet, if not change accordingly. You will also need to change the number if it is not starting on the first row.

The If function takes three parameters each separated by a comma, the first is called a condition. If the thing in the first parameter is true (The cell A1 in Sheet2 is the same as the A1 cell in Sheet1) the function will return the middle parameter that we set to be the value of the K1 cell in Sheet2. The third parameter is what happens if the condition is not true, for simplicity, I had it return nothing.

If the data is not the same, use a VLOOKUP

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A$1:K, 6, FALSE), "")
```

Comment: Hi Mark.  Thank you very much for your help.  I copied down the following formula but with no positive results =IF(Sheet2!A2 = A2, Sheet2!K2, "").  I made this video to show the attempt https://www.screencast.com/t/eGIqbiXi7ci

Comment: Oh, didn't realize they were not identical data sets. Just use this formula instead =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A$1:K, 6, FALSE), "") I need the reputation, so if this works, please accept the answer.

Comment: Okay. I'll check it tomorrow.  It is 10 p.m. here and I'm about brain dead

Comment: Still no luck.  Here were my results https://www.screencast.com/t/478SDABgIp

Answer (score 0):

paste this in cell **K2**: 

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A1:K, 11, 0)), )
```

[image: 9]

- `IFERROR(, )` - if an error occurs, output nothing
- `ARRAYFORMULA()` - assures that whole formula will be automated across sheet from a primary cell (in other words you don't need to copy this formula per every row)
- `VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A1:K, 11, 0)` - takes range `A2:A` and looks for matches in `Sheet2` on range `A1:K`. if a match exists it will bring up the **11**th column from `Sheet2`. lastly that `0` indicates that it won't end mixed up somewhere in the process of getting those email data